# Java DateTime parse

Tags: java, parsing, date, time

I have the following code to simply parse a date and time to a format

```
SimpleDateFormat sdfClient = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddhhmmss.s");
SimpleDateFormat sdfFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss");

pmList.add(sdfClient.format(sdfFormat.parse(pmData[k].retrievalTime)));
```

Wanna change the format to sdfClient but for some reason eclipse throws an error:

```
java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "20140623135000.0"
at java.text.DateFormat.parse(DateFormat.java:357)
at com.syntronic.client.GenerateCSV.writepmData(GenerateCSV.java:220)
at com.syntronic.client.GenerateCSV.writeMEData(GenerateCSV.java:187)
at com.syntronic.client.GenerateCSV.<init>(GenerateCSV.java:87)
at com.syntronic.client.Client.main(Client.java:213)
```

Anyone knows the reason why?

Comment: My guess is that `pmData[k]` holds format of the first kind, but you're parsing it as the second kind first.  Try swapping the calls using `sdfClient` and `sdfFormat`.

Comment: What's the type for pmData[k] array? sdfFormat.parse() accepts type string as param.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be just the other way around:

```
pmList.add(sdfFormat.format(sdfClient.parse(pmData[k].retrievalTime)));
```

**Explanation:**

```
pmList.add(
       sdfFormat.format(  <-- Gives a string 23/06/2014 01:50:00
            sdfClient.parse( <-- Gives a Date corresponding to the time 20140623135000.0
                  pmData[k].retrievalTime   <-- Time 20140623135000.0
               )
        )
        );
```

Answer (score 0):

You've got your formatter and parser mixed about

```
pmList.add(sdfClient.format(sdfFormat.parse(pmData[k].retrievalTime)));
```

Basically says, `"yyyyMMddhhmmss.s".format("dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss".parse(...))`

You want to use

```
pmList.add(sdfFormat.format(sdfClient.parse(pmData[k].retrievalTime)));
```

Instead...